# how to perform a case-insensitive attribute name in xslt 2.0

Tags: html, xslt-2.0

I want to set the attribute name as case-insensitive in xsl template

```
<xsl:template match="sec">
    <xsl:element name="span">
         <xsl:attribute name="(cdkDropListDropped)">
           <xsl:value-of select="drop($event)" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="cdkDropList">
           <xsl:value-of select="" />
         </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I used this code to render html and need the following as output

```
<span class='editable' data-element-name='sec' data-element-alias='Section' cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)='drop($event)'>
</span>
```

Comment: Attributes in XML and XHTML are always _case-sensitive_. But attributes in HTML _are not_. [Here](https://www.lifewire.com/html5-tags-case-sensitive-3467997) you get an overview. BTW you **cannot output** a _case-insensitive value_ at all, because a string always has some kind of case. It's either fully lower-case, fully upper-case or mixed. You can just be case-insensitive on reading the value.